# Flutter FirebaseMessaging: Decrypt received notifications

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to encrypt the content of a notification received with the Firebase_Messaging Plugin for Flutter before displaying it?

We don't want to send decrypted notifications directly so the device should locally encrypt the message using a locally saved key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging supports two message types:

- Notification messages, which are handled by the system if your app is not active, and are passed to your application code when it *is* active.
- Data messages, which are always passed to your application code.

Since the system won't be able to display your encrypted messages, you'll need to use only data messages when doing end-to-end encryption. You'll then encrypt the message either at the sender or on the server, and decrypt it in the `onMessage` handler of the recipient before displaying the notification.

See for an example of this split (but without encryption) this [example `onMessage` handler](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart) in the FlutterFire repo

Comment: Doesn't onMessage only run, when the app is active? And should I then send a LocalNotification to display the message?
It also seems like onMessage only runs, when the app is in foreground (at least on iOS)
Thank you very much

Comment: Data messages are always sent to `onMessage`. I'm indeed not sure how to handle this on iOS.